# Regex to get all alpha numeric fields except for comma, dash and single quote

Tags: javascript, regex

I am trying to strip out all non alpha numeric characters except for comma, dash and single quote. I know how to remove all non words from a string i.e

```
myString.replace(/\W/g,'');
```

But how do i do that with the exception of `,` `-` and `'` ? I tried

```
myString.replace(/\W+[^,]/g,'');
```

Because i know how to negate using the  `^` operator, just having trouble combining the regex.

Any help is appreciated. Thanks.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

`\w` is the inverse of `\W`, so you can just use `/[^\w,'-]/`

EDIT: in case underscore is also not desired: `/[^\w,'-]|_/`

Comment: `\w` also matches the underscore, which isn't wanted (it seems), references: [Mozilla Developer Network: 'Regular Expressions'](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Guide/Regular_Expressions).

Comment: @DavidThomas in that case the `\W` check would not work for underscore either

Answer (score 9):

The following character class matches a single character that belongs to the class of letters, numbers, comma, dash, and single quote.

```
[-,'A-Za-z0-9]
```

The following matches a character that is not one of those:

```
[^-,'A-Za-z0-9]
```

So

```
var stripped = myString.replace(/[^-,'A-Za-z0-9]+/g, '');
```