# Remove non numeric characters except dash

Tags: javascript

I need to remove all non numeric characters except the dash.
This is my attempt (based on: [Regex to get all alpha numeric fields except for comma, dash and single quote](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14762120/regex-to-get-all-alpha-numeric-fields-except-for-comma-dash-and-single-quote)):

```
var stripped = mystring.replace(/[-0-9]+/g, '');
```

But that doesn't work :-(

Answer (score 26, accepted):

I'd suggest:

```
var stripped = string.replace(/[^0-9\-]/g,'');
```

[JS Fiddle demo](http://jsfiddle.net/davidThomas/jewxbxjL/).

`^` in the character class (within the `[` and `]`) is the NOT operator, so it matches characters which are *not* `0-9` or the (escaped) `-` character.

As noted in the comment to this answer, by [Ted Hopp](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26202837/remove-non-numeric-characters-except-dash/26202844#comment41089255_26202844), it's not necessary to escape the `-` when it's the last character, but I habitually do so in order to save having to remember that proviso.

References:

- [JavaScript Regular Expressions](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Regular_Expressions).

Comment: No need to escape the dash when it's the last character in a class. Also, `0-9` could be replaced by `\d`. The regex could be `/[^\d-]/g`

Comment: Thanks, I've added that note to the answer but, as also noted, I always escape the dash in order to avoid having to remember the proviso (that it can be unescaped only when it's the last class). I really am that lazy... ;)

Comment: @TedHopp no need for ^ just use \D

Comment: @java-addict301 - What about the `-`? That also needs to not match.